# c# Static Lists used for two Combo issue

Tags: c#, .net

I pre-load some data from a remote sql database to speed up the application during use and I have several combo boxes on a form.

When the app loads, I preload a static List values called "usernames".

I set both the combo datasources to "usernames".  However, when I run the app and select a username from the first Combo, the same username is also selected on the 2nd combo and vice versa?

I know I could just pre-load the usernames as different statics but this will take additional time to load the app and I am sure this is just something very silly I am totally overlooking!

```
    static List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Usernames.Add("Paul");
        Usernames.Add("Elaine");
        Usernames.Add("Elliot");
        Usernames.Add("Matt");
        Usernames.Add("Brian");

        comboBox1.DataSource = Usernames;
        comboBox2.DataSource = Usernames;

    }
```

Thank you in advanced

Paul

Comment: Have your tried this code or not?

Comment: yes off course.  This is very simple example of what I am trying to acheive (much larger app that uses lots of remote online database calls).  Overal goal is to speed up the app to minimise database calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

```
static List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Usernames.Add("Paul");
    Usernames.Add("Elaine");
    Usernames.Add("Elliot");
    Usernames.Add("Matt");
    Usernames.Add("Brian");

    BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
    bs1.DataSource = Usernames;
    comboBox1.DataSource = bs1;
    BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
    bs2.DataSource = Usernames;
    comboBox2.DataSource = bs2;
}
```

A BindingSource instance maintains separate currency management (positioning on the underlying datasource) for the two combos

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you - (have to wait 32secs to accept this as the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could just pre-load the usernames as different statics but this will take additional time to load the app

It would not add significant time.  The main problem is you're adding values to a static list each time the page is loaded.  You only need to add them once.

You have a few options:

1. Load the names in the `Page`s *static* constructor:

   ```
   static List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();

   public static Form1()
   {
       Usernames.Add("Paul");
       Usernames.Add("Elaine");
       Usernames.Add("Elliot");
       Usernames.Add("Matt");
       Usernames.Add("Brian");
   }

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       comboBox1.DataSource = Usernames;
       comboBox2.DataSource = Usernames;

   }
   ```
2. Make the list non-static and load it each time:

   ```
   List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Usernames.Add("Paul");
       Usernames.Add("Elaine");
       Usernames.Add("Elliot");
       Usernames.Add("Matt");
       Usernames.Add("Brian");

       comboBox1.DataSource = Usernames;
       comboBox2.DataSource = Usernames;

   }
   ```

Comment: The app is a large Windows based c# .net bug tracking app that uses many database calls when opening and closing ticvkets.  Since moving the database from a local network to a remote web based location it has slowed down a lot because the database calls.  I wanted to pre-load all the common data (usernames, bug status names, and stuff that is re-used throught he app etc) which I have a 50% speed increase but using the static lists held as a static list<string> is causing a few issues as described.